# not select multiple ids

Tags: jquery

To select all children but a specific ID of a query, this would work:

`$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted)')`

How would you select for additional not wanted IDs?

Here are some attempts thus far:

```
$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted)' || ':not(#idNotWanted2)')
$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted) || :not(#idNotWanted2)')
$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted)' && ':not(#idNotWanted2)')
$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted) && :not(#idNotWanted2)')`
```

Do the selector queries need to be assigned to an array, then remove the ID cases? or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either do this:

```
$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted):not(#idNotWanted2)')
```

Or, **the better way**, like this:

```
$('.yourClass').children(':not(#idNotWanted, #idNotWanted2)')
```

Separate your IDs with a comma inside your `:not()` selector. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/);

> All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a)`.